# Using AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter before api 11

Tags: android, adapter, android-adapter, android-syncadapter

How do I use AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter for minSDK lower than API-11? The following constructor is complaining about needing API-11.

```
public DogSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize, boolean allowParallelSyncs) {
    super(context, autoInitialize, allowParallelSyncs);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the documentation:

Api level 5:

```
public AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter (Context context, boolean autoInitialize)
```

Api level 11:

```
public AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter (Context context, boolean autoInitialize, boolean allowParallelSyncs)
```

So you just need to implement both constructors, and then call one or other:

```
if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    sSyncAdapter = new NotificationsSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true, true);
                } else {
                    sSyncAdapter = new NotificationsSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
                }
            }
```

Comment: So there is no parallel sync convenience in API less than 11? That was essentially the gist of my question. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: No, below 11 you cannot have parallel syncs

Comment: wow. That's too bad. I was hoping I could use `android.support.v4.content. AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter`. That's quite  a bummer.